# JPackage: encoding of parameters (Windows)

Tags: java, character-encoding, jpackage

I have generated a Windows executable for my Java application using jpackage (Java 14, OpenJDK). It works fine, but there is a last glitch that troubles me: The application is associated with files with a certain suffix. On double clicking such a file in Windows Explorer, the application will start and open the file. This also works fine as long as the file path consists of 7-bit-ASCII characters only. As soon as there is an Umlaut or something similar, however, (as in "c:\myFolder\Ä.exb") I get an error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Ã„.exb (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
        at org.exmaralda.partitureditor.jexmaralda.sax.BasicTranscriptionSaxReader.readFromFile(BasicTranscriptionSaxReader.java:60)
```

Obviously, this is an encoding problem. The file path is in UTF-8, but it is read as ISO-8859-1 (?). Where would I tell jpackage to expect arguments to `main(String[] args)` to be encoded in UTF-8? I tried:

```
            <arg value="--java-options"/><arg value="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"/>     
            <arg value="--java-options"/><arg value="-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8"/>
```

in the ant job which calls jpackage, but that didn't change anything.
Anybody have an idea where to look or what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Worth checking JDK bug database or raising new issue to do with the launcher. I see same problem if renaming a file with umlaut, regardless of the file.encoding. From same CMD window `java.exe classname Ä.jpg` works fine but packaged version of same class `myclass.exe Ä.jpg` runs with wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the confirmation. This seems to have been fixed between OpenJDK's Java 14 and 15. When using jpackage from JDK 15, the problem disappears. :-)

Comment: Note that jpackage add-launcher does not work in JDK15 which prevents creation use of multiple executables.